# How long time does it take to renew a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, visa-renewals

I have a single-entry schengen visa, ending in 27 July. But I will exit the EU country in 9th, so I won’t be able to use that visa anymore. My question is; I have a new trip plan between 22 and 24 July, so can I apply for a new schengen visa?

Comment: Yes, you can apply. Do you think that might be a problem for some reason?

Comment: Whether a new visa application can be *decided* in less than two weeks is a different matter...

Answer (score 1):

You could apply for a visa extension.

While waiting for a decision you are allowed to remain in the Schengen area.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, your visa extension application can take a few days, up to a month to be processed.

During this time, you are permitted to remain in the country where you submitted your application even after your visa expires, but not to travel to the other Schengen countries.